# In R, how do I translate one record with a single comma-separated field into multiple records?

Tags: r

I'm working in R.

I have a dataset in which some records contain a list of cities and counties instead of just one city or county.  I'm looking for a way to transpose that data into "long" format, in which there would be multiple records, each with one city/county.

reshape assumes multiple columns instead of a comma-separated list in one column.

strsplit can split the entry into a vector of values, but then how do I make the new records containing all of the same other information, add it to the data.frame, and remove the original entry?

Thanks!

Comment: There are multiple possible interpretations of your setup. Could you show an example (preferrably reproducible) of what you have and what you would like to get?

Answer (score 4):

You can use the function `colsplit` in package `reshape2`:

```
x <- c("a, b", "c, d", "e")
library(reshape2)
colsplit(x, ",", names=c("City", "County"))

  City County
1    a      b
2    c      d
3    e
```

Answer (score 1):

```
d = as.data.frame(do.call(rbind, strsplit(dtaFrame$cityCountry, ",")))
colnames(d) = c("city", "country")
cbind(dtaFrame[,-which(colnames(dtaFrame)=="cityCountry",], d)
```

should do it.